# WPF + MVVM + Enterprise Library Validation Block

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, enterprise-library, idataerrorinfo

I'm starting a new WPF MVVM App and I'm trying to get an idea how to handle validation "better than I have done before" - before I used `IDataErrorInfo` on the model and viewModel. It worked ok but it was difficult to extend later on and needed lots of manual wiring in most cases. I'm sure that `IDataErrorInfo` is still a good way for hooking up the ViewModel validation but I would like to have a go with the Enterprise Library to validate the Model but is there a way to actually validate one property at a time instead of a whole object?

Or is there some other clever way to use the config generated by EL?

Any ideas or other suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I think I found something more or less what I've been looking for:
(from http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/233057)

```
Type type = typeof(Customer);
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("Name");

string ruleset = string.Empty;
var source = ValidationSpecificationSource.All;
var builder = new ReflectionMemberValueAccessBuilder();

Validator validator =
    PropertyValidationFactory.GetPropertyValidator(
        type, property, ruleset, source, builder);

ValidationResults results = validator.Validate(customer);
```

But that would mean that my `ViewModel` has to work on a model instance rather than doing something like:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
   get { ... }
   set { ...}
}
```

It looks like I have to work on a model instance or validate in the `ViewModel` layer - which I was hoping to avoid.

... or am I missing something really well-known and obvious to most people ... ?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: So, you don't want to validate in the ViewModel nor the Model?  You have to validate somewhere.  IMHO, start writing hacky code and worry about "the correct way" later.